# Heliohost and Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Hey,
actually I'm pretty new to webdevelopment. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to deploy my Rails application to Heliohost and I seriously lost.

Can someone please provide me with a step-by-step tutorial for heliohost?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother wasting your time with heliohost. If you need a Ruby (on Rails) deployment environment go with [Heroku](http://heroku.com/). It is free (for small projects) and can be setup in under ten minutes.

Comment: why? do you have anything against heliohost?

Comment: @Mhmd At the time (five years ago) Heroku was far and away the easiest way to get a Ruby on Rails app up and running. I've been trying to access Heliohost now to remember what it even is and the page took over a few minutes to load (I was actually surprised Chrome didn't time out). This might be a strange coincidence but I've got a feeling my original assessment is accurate.